# JQuerymobile textbox and button on sameline

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/demos/controlgroup/#Textinputs
```

I followed the above link from jquery mobile. It doesn't work as expected !
Can someone help

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the height too:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="text" id="search-control-group" data-wrapper-class="controlgroup-textinput ui-btn">
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>

.controlgroup-textinput{
    height: 20px;
    padding-top:.22em;
    padding-bottom:.22em;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rmdd2426/)**

Answer (score 0):

**To anyone having the same issue after using the code from the jquerymobile demos!**

If you copy html or css content from the demos page, make sure to remove all leading whitespaces (indentation) first and add your own!
The demos page uses some other invisible non breakable spaces that prevent proper css parsing in most browsers!

I had the same issue and when looking into the css parsed by chrome it was marking

`"    padding-top: .22em;"`

as invalid css, because of those non breakable spaces.